# A little confused on Creating Your own NameServer and DNS

Tags: linux, domain-name-system, nameserver

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is a glue record?](https://serverfault.com/questions/309622/what-is-a-glue-record)

My registrar refused to provide DNS service anymore.

It only allows me to add my own NameServers like: ns1.myexample.com, ns2.myexample.com

I have bought a VPS and follow this tutorial:

http://pinoygeeks.net/blog/how-to-setup-nsd-name-server-daemon-in-ubuntu-debian-bind-alternative/

What would the NameServers be? I mean, it can not be ns1.myexample.com, because ns1.myexample.com has not been resolved yet. so it must be something else.

Comment: See http://serverfault.com/questions/309622/what-is-a-glue-record

Comment: I disagree this is a duplicate. This answer is far more helpful and easy to understand than suggested duplicate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you own the myexample.com domain, then your registrar "must" allow you to define the IP addresses of name servers in that domain.  Perhaps not through their control panel, you may have to contact them directly.

So you would define

ns1.myexample.com as 1.1.1.1
ns2.myexample.com as 1.1.1.2

for example, then these name servers would be registered in the .com zone.  Note that if they do not provide this service, then they are not acting as registrars and so should not be selling domains.

The IP addresses 1.1.1.1 and 1.1.1.2 are the DNS servers that you intend use to for your domain.

So the way it works is someone says "what is the IP address of www.myexample.com".  The first question goes to the .com nameservers -> "what are the addresses of the name servers for myexample.com" - the .com nameservers respond, and then the query goes on to the actual name servers to resolve www.myexample.com

Comment: Thanks so much Paul. You are right. It is under the "Name Server Registration" which was ignored by me. :)