# Misconfigured DNS / Nameserver?

Tags: domain-name-system, domain, bind, nameserver, glue-record

I just moved my website to a new server. New server IP = 217.23.9.121

I'm running my domain on [IntoDns.com](http://www.intodns.com)

It showing me errors such as:

```
-Missing nameservers reported by your nameservers
-Nameservers not responding
-and more
```

My setup is shown in this [Screenshot](http://www.tiikoni.com/tis/view/?id=7b7333d)

My website runs on nginx

My question is, why am I getting these errors ? Is my dns/nameserver setup (in the screenshot) incorrect? Also, my visitors who have already propagated to the new server IP report the website is not working.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: i edited my post to make it more clear

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Website software is irrelevant here
2. Your config (according to screenshot and AXFR) is extremely bad - re-think and re-read, there and how use @ shorthand

Food for brain

- Quering 217.23.9.121 for {animefushigi.com.,AXFR}

  ; Answer ID: 41  QR: true  OPCODE: QUERY  AA: true  TC: false  RD: false
  ; RA: true  RCODE: NOERROR  qc 1  an 8  au 0  ad 0

  ; Question section:
  ;animefushigi.com. IN AXFR

  ; Answer section:

  animefushigi.com. 1m IN SOA ns1.animefushigi.com. admin.animefushigi.com. 2012022401 60 900 60 60

  animefushigi.com. 1m IN NS ns1.animefushigi.com.

  animefushigi.com. 1m IN NS ns2.animefushigi.com.

  animefushigi.com. 1m IN A 217.23.9.121

  ns1.animefushigi.com. 1m IN A **217.23.9.121**

  ns2.animefushigi.com. 1m IN A **217.23.9.121**

  www.animefushigi.com. 1m IN CNAME animefushigi.com.

  animefushigi.com. 1m IN SOA ns1.animefushigi.com. admin.animefushigi.com. 2012022401 60 900 60 60

(compare with your amount of RR in zone)

- nslookup

  nslookup NS1.ANIMEFUSHIGI.COM
  Server:  server1.eka-net.ru
  Address:  10.0.10.1

  Non-authoritative answer:
  Name:    NS1.ANIMEFUSHIGI.COM
  Address:  **217.23.1.90**

  nslookup NS2.ANIMEFUSHIGI.COM
  Server:  server1.eka-net.ru
  Address:  10.0.10.1

  Non-authoritative answer:
  Name:    NS2.ANIMEFUSHIGI.COM
  Address:  **217.23.1.90**

And unused 217.23.1.90 still serve zone (hidden primary) and declared as authoritative server.

**Resume**

Kill outdated zone on old host

In registrar data fix records about your NSes and write IP

Two NSes on same IP is useless thing - spread in different nets or remove NS ns2

Answer (score 3):

Because your authoritative name servers are within the domain that they're authoritative for, you have a loop.  See [this question](https://serverfault.com/q/309622/72586) for a detailed explanation.

What you need is to set up DNS glue records with your registrar - this allows for the delegating server (the `.com` servers) to provide a pointer to the IP address of the authoritative server for your domain, breaking the loop.

Comment: setup **correct** glue-records

Answer (score 1):

Note: I am assuming that ANIMEFUSHIGI.COM is your domain name from the screenshot.

The name servers of the domain NS1.ANIMEFUSHIGI.COM and NS2.ANIMEFUSHIGI.COM do not resolve.

```
dig NS1.ANIMEFUSHIGI.COM

; <<>> DiG 9.7.3 <<>> NS1.ANIMEFUSHIGI.COM
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: SERVFAIL, id: 50694
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 0, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 0

;; QUESTION SECTION:
;NS1.ANIMEFUSHIGI.COM.      IN  A

;; Query time: 637 msec
;; SERVER: 4.2.2.2#53(4.2.2.2)
;; WHEN: Fri Feb 24 10:15:50 2012
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 38


dig NS2.ANIMEFUSHIGI.COM

; <<>> DiG 9.7.3 <<>> NS2.ANIMEFUSHIGI.COM
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: SERVFAIL, id: 10472
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 0, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 0

;; QUESTION SECTION:
;NS2.ANIMEFUSHIGI.COM.      IN  A

;; Query time: 411 msec
;; SERVER: 121.242.190.181#53(121.242.190.181)
;; WHEN: Fri Feb 24 10:16:21 2012
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 38
```

When you mention you've moved your website, did you move the DNS of the domain as well ? If yes, then you'll need to configure DNS on the new server.

If the DNS is on the same server and only the website has been moved, then you'd have to only change the DNS A record of the domain leaving everything else intact.

Comment: The dns has been setup on the new server, as shown in the screenshot. Ns1 and ns2 have A records to our IP

Comment: Change authoritative DNS, when you change webhost is always **bad idea**. Change authoritative DNS, which referenced inside zone, when you change webhost - just **terrible idea**