# Why my domain register requires name servers ip address?

Tags: domain-name-system

I would like to move my domain from main domain registrar name server to amazon Route 53.

The problem is that amazon gives only dns names and my registrar also requires the ip.

Is it safe to use the ip found with the host command? Would my domain work correctly if Amazon decided to change DNS ips?

**//added more info:**

whois for my domain returns:

```
beast:~ viroos$ whois domain.name

DOMAIN NAME:           domain.name
registrant type:       organization
nameservers:           nms1.onet.pl.
                       nms2.onet.pl.
created:               20xx.xx.xx 01:02:22
last modified:         20xx.xx.xx 12:01:20
renewal date:          20xx.xx.xx 01:02:22

no option



REGISTRAR:
Grupa Onet.pl S.A.
ul. G. Zapolskiej 44
30 - 126 Krakow
Polska/Poland
+48. 12 2600200
bok@onet.pl

WHOIS displays data with a delay not exceeding 15 minutes in relation to the .pl Registry system
Registrant data available at http://dns.pl/cgi-bin/en_whois.pl
```

dig my new ns:

```
beast:~ viroos$ dig SOA in domain.name @ns-1317.awsdns-36.org.

; <<>> DiG 9.6-ESV-R4-P3 <<>> SOA in domain.name @ns-1317.awsdns-36.org.
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 64706
;; flags: qr aa rd; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 1, AUTHORITY: 4, ADDITIONAL: 0
;; WARNING: recursion requested but not available

;; QUESTION SECTION:
;domain.name.           IN  SOA

;; ANSWER SECTION:
domain.name.        900 IN  SOA ns-1317.awsdns-36.org. awsdns-hostmaster.amazon.com. 1 7200 900 1209600 86400

;; AUTHORITY SECTION:
domain.name.        172800  IN  NS  ns-475.awsdns-59.com.
domain.name.        172800  IN  NS  ns-526.awsdns-01.net.
domain.name.        172800  IN  NS  ns-1317.awsdns-36.org.
domain.name.        172800  IN  NS  ns-1756.awsdns-27.co.uk.

;; Query time: 300 msec
;; SERVER: 205.251.197.37#53(205.251.197.37)
;; WHEN: Wed Apr 11 17:55:47 2012
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 227
```

new DNSes IPs:

```
beast:~ viroos$ host ns-475.awsdns-59.com
ns-475.awsdns-59.com has address 205.251.193.219

beast:~ viroos$ host ns-526.awsdns-01.net.
ns-526.awsdns-01.net has address 205.251.194.14
```

And my question is: Is it safe to fill web form in my current registrar web panel with following data (he requires exact 2 servers). Of coures I added appropriate A, MX and CNAME entries on new server:

```
NS1 name: ns-475.awsdns-59.com NS1 ip: 205.251.193.219
NS2 name: ns-526.awsdns-01.net NS2 ip: 205.251.194.14
```

Comment: I also asked the same question to my domain registrar tech support but I didn't get any answer :(

Comment: Are you certain that it won't let you submit the form without IP addresses?  It shouldn't accept addresses for name servers that aren't in your domain; the TLD servers sure won't either.  If they force you to enter data in those fields, enter junk data like `127.0.0.1`.

Comment: Yes. I'm sure about it. Thanks for idea if junk data. I think it could be safer (more predictable) then entering resolved ip.

Comment: Yeah - obviously your registrar shouldn't be giving the TLD servers a glue record for a domain that you don't own, and even if they do, the TLD servers won't accept it - that would be a major security problem.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

They have a field for IP addresses in order to utilize [glue records](https://serverfault.com/questions/309622/what-is-a-glue-record) - but they shouldn't be required.  If they are, your registrar needs to fix their management tools.

The `NS` record delegation that's configured for your domain must be DNS names; an IP address is only useful when the servers are within your own domain.

Comment: This is confused nonsense; IP addresses for nameservers are unrelated to glue records, and glue records are **required** whenever the nameservers for a zone are inside the delegated zone, regardless of who hosts the delegated zone.

Comment: @adaptr Huh?  What I'm saying is that the only reason that the registrar has fields for IP addresses in their delegation interface is to facilitate the creation of glue records in the event that the name servers are within the domain.  How is that nonsense, exactly?  He's not changing registrars, he's changing DNS hosts.

Comment: @adaptr IP addresses are only for Glue records, as Shane said. If you don't own the domain of the DNS host you should NEVER be entering IPs, as those Glue records don't belong to you.

Comment: That was some brainfart; I could have sworn he was talking about switching registrars. Perhaps because the only time you **need** to mention registrars is when you're changing them...

Answer (score 1):

Your current **registrar** probably also hosts the zone; you can easily verify this by running `whois domain.name`.

If you move the domain to another registrar, they will no longer host the zone for you, and you will not be able to use the same nameserver IPs for the new registrar (since they belong to the old one.)

Just tell the new registrar that you want them to host the zone for you.

Comment: I fixed spelling. I also added more info - whois for my domain and dig for new server. Is it safe to move my domain to new servers?