# How does a domain host itself authoritatively?

Tags: domain-name-system, domain, vps

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is a glue record?](https://serverfault.com/questions/309622/what-is-a-glue-record)

Suppose that I want to have custom nameservers that authoritatively host `mydomain.com`: `ns1.mydomain.com` and `ns2.mydomain.com`. They would need to be resolvable somehow for the rest of the internet to be able to use them, but how is that possible when the nameserver records are rooted under the domain that they're authoritative for?

Comment: @Chris Edit submitted. I'm fine with leaving this closed as a duplicate, but people who don't understand what glue records are typically don't know what to call them either. The proposed edits should help those people find their way to the linked question.