# Why I can not link my domain to a new nameservers?

Tags: domain-name-system, dns-hosting

I have a domain name for my online website and it works fine I change the hosting server for some reason and now everything is going bad.
I can not link my domain to the nameservers for example my old domain and nameservers was:

```
example.com
n1.example.com
n2.example.com
```

Now I want to change them to :

```
example.com
n1.newexample.com
n2.newexample.com
```

I link the n1 & n2 to the IPs that I get from my hosting company but when I try to link my domain with the new nameservers it gives me an error (Not exist) and that is not reasonable because I try to link them to another domain name and it works and I try to ping them and they response. 
I do not get that can anybody help me to understand what is going on here please?

Comment: HOW do you link them and what is the exact error message? More Info on what you are doing exactly would be helpful, at least for me.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Changing nameservers for a domain name issue on name.com](http://serverfault.com/questions/511597/changing-nameservers-for-a-domain-name-issue-on-name-com)

Comment: I link them in the hosting server (configurations).I move my website to another hosting company and when i tried to change the old nameservers to the new ones i get an error saying this nameservers are not exist. while i used them with another domain name and it recognized them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is vague.  We really have no idea what tool your hosting company provides for you to manage your DNS, nor can we diagnose your problem when you have anonymized your question using `example.com`.  Consider updating your question with all of the specific details intact.

That said, I would speculate that you can't use `n1.newexample.com` and `n2.newexample.com` as nameservers because [glue records](https://serverfault.com/questions/309622/what-is-a-glue-record) don't exist for them yet.  You add the glue records by telling your domain name registrar (*not* your hosting provider) that you want to use `n1.newexample.com` and `n2.newexample.com` as your nameservers.  (Your domain name registrar and hosting company are separate entities, I hope?)

As for why it worked for another domain but not `example.com`, it's probably because your other domain was not a `.com`.  Each top-level domain registry maintains a separate set of glue records.

Comment: that is right the domain which is worked with is .org domain,so now you are telling me that i should ask name.com to add a glue record for my nameservers??

Comment: by the way name.com offer a testing name servers like ns1.name.com and they work??? they are .com. how did they worked?

Comment: Yes, that's what I'm suggesting.  And of course, name.com has already registered glue records for ns1.name.com, so you don't have to.

Comment: but how come that my old nameservers worked fine and they are .com also and i did not ask name.com to register a glue records for them

Comment: The simple explanation would be that your old nameservers had glue records in .com and your new ones don't.