# Fixing my glue records

Tags: whois, glue-record, domain-name-system

In reference to [this question](https://serverfault.com/questions/522722/are-these-nameservers-configured-properly), I've been working with skv to fix their glue records and I'm sort of wondering what I should be seeing. They've called DNSMadeEasy and got assistance creating the glue records.

Here's what I see when I query a TLD server:

```
dig +norec @e.gtld-servers.net. skv.com NS

; <<>> DiG 9.8.3-P1 <<>> +norec @e.gtld-servers.net. skv.com NS
; (1 server found)
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 36825
;; flags: qr; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 0, AUTHORITY: 2, ADDITIONAL: 12

;; QUESTION SECTION:
;skv.com.           IN  NS

;; AUTHORITY SECTION:
skv.com.        172800  IN  NS  ns1.primuscomputing.com.
skv.com.        172800  IN  NS  ns2.primusnetworks.com.

;; ADDITIONAL SECTION:
ns1.primuscomputing.com. 172800 IN  A   208.80.124.4
ns1.primuscomputing.com. 172800 IN  A   208.80.125.4
ns1.primuscomputing.com. 172800 IN  A   208.80.126.4
ns1.primuscomputing.com. 172800 IN  A   208.80.127.4
ns1.primuscomputing.com. 172800 IN  A   208.94.148.4
ns1.primuscomputing.com. 172800 IN  A   208.94.149.4
ns2.primusnetworks.com. 172800  IN  A   208.80.124.4
ns2.primusnetworks.com. 172800  IN  A   208.80.125.4
ns2.primusnetworks.com. 172800  IN  A   208.80.126.4
ns2.primusnetworks.com. 172800  IN  A   208.80.127.4
ns2.primusnetworks.com. 172800  IN  A   208.94.148.4
ns2.primusnetworks.com. 172800  IN  A   208.94.149.4
```

This seems to indicate that the glue records are in place.

However, if I perform a whois on skv.com, I don't see IP addresses next to the servers listed. I called Network Solutions to ask them and they said that information cannot be altered and indicated that the information would be added automatically?

The other thing is that when I don't receive an ADDITIONAL section when I dig skv.com NS.

Is it possible these items will get automatically updated as the changes propagates? Or is there more I need to do?

Thanks, all!

Comment: Yell at NetSol _louder_.

Comment: So you're saying I should be able to make this change. Have you done it before with them?

Comment: Hell, even _GoDaddy_ lets you fix your own glue records. For NetSol to _not_ do it is ridiculous.

Comment: I think I got the answer I needed from NetSol. What about the fact that "dig skv.com NS" doesn't show the ADDITIONAL section?

Comment: @tcv That doesn't display glue; it came from the authoritative nameservers.

Comment: I am curious, though, why I get that ADDITIONAL section when I dig my own NS? I guess the records could be there but they're not necessary?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By all appearances your glue is fine and the WHOIS database is running behind.

- WHOIS databases are not necessarily up to date. What you're being told is that the nameserver information within WHOIS is automatically populated and you can't edit this. Since WHOIS is purely informative and not relied upon for any type of nameserver authority, this is acceptable.
- `dig <somedomain> NS` does not display the glue that nameservers use to find a domain. As your dig output against the root nameservers shows, the glue is present. The DNS response that comes back with the missing additional records originates from the authoritative nameservers for `skv.com`, which can only be fixed by the parties who operate the nameservers.

-

```
$dig @ns2.primusnetworks.com +norecurse skv.com NS

; <<>> DiG 9.7.3 <<>> @ns2.primusnetworks.com +norecurse skv.com NS
; (1 server found)
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 56608
;; flags: qr aa; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 3, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 0

;; QUESTION SECTION:
;skv.com.                       IN      NS

;; ANSWER SECTION:
skv.com.                86400   IN      NS      ns2.primusnetworks.com.
skv.com.                86400   IN      NS      ns3.primusnetworks.com.
skv.com.                86400   IN      NS      ns1.primuscomputing.com.

;; Query time: 24 msec
;; SERVER: 208.80.124.4#53(208.80.124.4)
;; WHEN: Fri Jul 12 19:43:33 2013
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 110
```

Keep in mind that the missing `ADDITIONAL` section is not *strictly* necessary: the `minimal-responses` option in BIND explicitly disables it in reply packets except in cases where required by RFC. (i.e. delegations)

Comment: Thanks, Andrew. I have a suspicion why the whois is not autopopulating, but do I need to make sure that information is there?

Comment: @tcv Nope. The nameserver data in WHOIS is for information purposes only and is not a part of the DNS spec at all. I honestly think the problem will go away if you ignore it for awhile.

Comment: Thanks again, Andrew. I've had to go through third and fourth parties to get all the done. The pace is out of my hands and slow so I'm frustrated. I want it all done. Thanks for your reassurances.

Answer (score 2):

From http://www.webhostingbuzz.com/wiki/how-add-glue-records/...

1. Go to Network Solutions account page
2. Log in to your Account Manager using your username and password
3. Click on “My Products & Services” tab
4. Select “My Domain Names”
5. Scroll down to “More Domain Options” section and click on “Manage Name Servers” icon
6. Input the primary nameserver you want to create and click “Go”
7. You will need to enter the IP address for your new name server, once it is entered click “Go”.
8. You will be asked to confirm and save the changes. Click “Save Changes” if you are satisfied with your entry.
9. A confirmation screen will confirm that your changes have been saved.

Repeat to add secondary name server with your IP address.

Comment: I got as far as step 6. I think I'll need to get NetSol to address it. Sigh.

Comment: It's 2020 and netsol still has the glue configuration hidden in such an obscure place that their support can't even find it.