# None of the nameservers responded correctly

Tags: domain-name-system

Recently I purchased a VPS and wanted to use my already existing domain for it. So the host pointed it to my server, and now all I need to do is go into ISPConfig and change some server settings to "point at the domain" (if that's the way to say it?).

Here is a tutorial I followed, which was recommended by my host:

http://www.howtoforge.com/how-to-run-your-own-name-server-with-ispconfig-3-and-fast-hosts

https://i.stack.imgur.com/CBJ9L.png

However, still, nobody can connect to my website. And using a dns lookup site, I get this:

```
Searching for rscharts.com. A record at A.ROOT-SERVERS.NET. [198.41.0.4] ...took 2 ms
Searching for rscharts.com. A record at c.gtld-servers.net. [192.26.92.30] ...took 96 ms
Searching for rscharts.com. A record at ns1.rscharts.com. [212.1.209.246] null
Searching for rscharts.com. A record at ns2.rscharts.com. [212.1.209.246] null
Searching for rscharts.com. A record at ns2.rscharts.com. [212.1.209.246] null
Searching for rscharts.com. A record at ns1.rscharts.com. [212.1.209.246] null
None of the nameservers responded correctly.
```

Comment: [Administration panels are off topic](http://serverfault.com/help/on-topic). [Even the presence of an administration panel on a system,](http://meta.serverfault.com/q/6538/118258) because they [take over the systems in strange and non-standard ways, making it difficult or even impossible for actual system administrators to manage the servers normally](http://meta.serverfault.com/a/3924/118258), and tend to indicate low-quality questions from *users* with insufficient knowledge for this site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The summary of my answer is that I've never used ISPConfig, but that the issue does appear to be on your DNS server. You (or your hosting company) need to figure out why the DNS server isn't responding to queries.

Here's the long answer:

I'm not quite sure what you're asking here. It seems you're trying to run your own DNS service (Name Servers), is this correct? Your .png and domain WHOIS for rscharts.com indicate the following name servers for your domain:

```
 Name Servers:  
    ns1.rscharts.com
    ns2.rscharts.com
```

According to your A records that you've defined, you have both NS1 and NS2 pointed to the same server (212.1.209.246). As a side note, that's not recommended (nor is it RFC compliant). The reason you have two name servers is so that you have DNS redundancy should 1 DNS server fail.

But back to your question... Let me try to explain, briefly, the steps in running your own DNS servers (since that's what it looks like you're trying to do):

1. Register your Domain at the Registrar (in your case, according to WHOIS results, HOSTING24.COM).
2. Setup your Name Servers on your *two* different servers / IP addresses
3. Register your Name Servers at the Registrar ([setup your DNS Glue Record](https://serverfault.com/questions/309622/what-is-a-glue-record))
4. Setup your DNS Zone on your Name Servers, and make sure ns1 and ns2 are define.

Now, on to your specific question:
I can't be sure, but it would appear that your DNS servers aren't configured properly, and aren't actually responding to queries:

```
[david@elmer ~]$ dig rscharts.com

; <<>> DiG 9.8.2rc1-RedHat-9.8.2-0.17.rc1.el6_4.6 <<>> rscharts.com
;; global options: +cmd
;; connection timed out; no servers could be reached
```

I like Pingdom's DNS check service as a good resource too: http://dnscheck.pingdom.com/?domain=rscharts.com

There's a number of things you can check, but this is certainly on your DNS server:

- Make sure your firewall allows incoming queries
- Make sure your DNS servers are actually running / listening to queries - If this is run through ISPConfig (and it does look like you've configured ISPConfig properly), then make sure the DNS service is turned on. I'm not familiar with ISPConfig, but surely that's something that your hosting company can help you with. If they can't, then go find a new hosting company, or get rid of ISPConfig, and run BIND yourself.

Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

If you're going to run your own DNS servers, THEY need to be advertised by your registrar.

You need to have at least two "reliable" DNS servers each respond to every domain name with what we call "a zone file", though technically, it doesn't have to be in a single file - or, I suppose, even be in a file, though that's how it's ordinarily done by all the DNS servers of which I am aware.

If you have a competent registrar, like, say, GoDaddy.com, they already provide you DNS services that are free with your registration (at competitive cost) and all these problems go away.

There are some advantages to running your own, but they are few, and they are not recommended for the beginner. But if you insist, you'll need to become an expert. Running name servers is not really a novice level task - sorry!

Again, if you want to persist, I recommend NameD...Follow your nose!