# Why do nameservers have their own names?

Tags: domain-name-system, nameserver, fqdn, tld

For example, lets say there is a hosting company, hostingcompany.com, with nameserver ns1.hostingcompany.com.  When I type hostingcompany.com into my browser, my computer contacts a top level .com domain nameserver, which in turn contacts the name server for hostingcompany.com to get the A record for hostingcompany.com or any of its subdomains.  Isn't this circular, since the FQDN for the nameserver is a subdomain of the domain name itself?  In other words, in order to find the IP address of ns1.hostingcompany.com, we need a nameserver for *.hostingcompany.com, which is itself?  What am I missing?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The title of your question is asking a different question than the one in the question body.

### Why does this not create circular dependencies?

Shane covered the topic of glue records. For further information, refer to [What is a glue record?](https://serverfault.com/questions/309622/what-is-a-glue-record).

### Why are NS records defined within zone files (if glue records are preferred)?

This gets somewhat complicated. There is a DNS term called *bailiwick* that refers to whether a DNS record is "within the authority" of a higher level *label*, or record.

- `ns1.example.com.` is within the bailiwick of `example.com.`.
- `ns1.contoso.com.` is not within the bailiwick of `example.com.`.
- `example.com.` and `contoso.com.` are both within the bailiwick of `com.`.
- `com.` is within the bailiwick of `.` (root).

Broken down like this, it becomes easier to explain: glue is needed for referrals to nameservers *inside of bailiwick*.

If `sub.example.org.` (not in the examples above) specifies a nameserver of `ns1.contoso.com.`, it is not necessary to supply glue. If it were to do so, this would called "out of bailiwick glue" which is actually considered to be *bad*:

- The IP address of `ns1.contoso.com.` would have to be managed on two different nameservers.
- `ns1.contoso.com.` may be owned by a completely separate company.
- The operators of `ns1.contoso.com.` are probably aware of the fact that they host `sub.example.org.`, but they have no way of knowing whether the nameservers for `example.org.` are providing out of bailiwick glue for their nameserver. If they change the IP address of `ns1.contoso.com.`, this will completely break `sub.example.net.` until the owners of `example.net.` notice this and either correct the glue, or remove it.

Answer (score 4):

The name can be resolved because there are [glue records](https://serverfault.com/questions/309622/what-is-a-glue-record) present in the name server for the TLD, `.com` in this case.

The answer providing the name servers for `hostingcompany.com` also includes the `A` records that the TLD servers have for the name servers, so the resolving system (usually a recursive name server your computer's querying, not your computer itself) knows where to look.