# How to specify a DNS Slave server, that is on a different domain, in the appropriate zone file on the master naming server?

Tags: linux, domain-name-system, centos, bind

I am unsure if my question makes sense, but I am working on configuring a DNS Master/Slave setup. We currently have two domains. For privacy purposes, I will use "example" as my domain, we have `example.net` and `ec2.example.net`. Our Master DNS server is currently on `example.net` and we want our slave on `ec2.example.net`.

How do I specify the slave naming server in the appropriate zone file on the Master naming server? I attempted using its FQDN of `dns02.ec2.example.net` and when I restart DNS and related processes, it fails because it can't locate `dns02.ec2.example.net`. What is needed?

Answer (score 1):

This won't work, because zone transfers are handled on a zone-to-zone basis. You can't transfer a full zone to a partial zone.

That said, it's possible to define a more specific zone on your master server called `ec2.example.net.`. Doing this will hide `ec2` and all records beneath it in your `example.net.` zone, so you will need to ensure that all of those records are copied over into the new zone. It would then be possible to transfer this zone to other servers without including your `example.net.` data.

**DANGER**: If you want to host these on completely different servers, this will require [glue records](https://serverfault.com/q/309622/152073) in the `example.net.` zone for the `dns01.ec2` and `dns02.ec2`:

```
dns01.ec2 IN A 203.0.113.1
dns02.ec2 IN A 203.0.113.2
```