# How to include a file in a zone file (using $INCLUDE directive) in nsd name server

Tags: nsd

I want  to include a file in the zone file in a nsd name server implementation, using the `$INCLUDE` directive.

When I reload the zone with the **`nsd-control reload <zone>`** command, in the log file I notice an error about not finding the include file.

Does anyone know how to include the file in the zone file definition? NSD seems to lack a thorough documentation (like BIND).

Comment: Does `nsd-checkzone` the NSD zone file syntax checker give any meaningful output?

Comment: When i include the file with quotes ("") the nsd-checkzone does not complain. When i remove the quotes, the checker is ok. But the log file, in both cases, complain about not being able to find the file.

Comment: Are you using and absolute path `$INCLUDE "/var/named/inc/default-records.inc" `  or a relative path?

Comment: Actually, i use this directive: $INCLUDE /usr/local/etc/nsd/zones/forward/COMMON. I want to have in a common file things like SOA and NS, MX records, which are the same for all the zones/subzones

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your comment:

> Actually, I use this directive: `$INCLUDE /usr/local/etc/nsd/zones/forward/COMMON`. I want to have in a common file things like SOA and NS, MX records, which are the same for all the zones/subzones

Where my first response is that setting the SOA record in a master include file is a bad idea as that means that all your DNS zones will have the same version number and an update to one will require reloading all zones.

The use of the $INCLUDE directive is established in [RFC 1035](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc1035.txt) and one of the design goals `nsd` is to be completely RFC compliant.

Unless you're running into a simple error in the file-system permissions it seems likely you're running into the requirements that are set in RFC 1035 section 5.2 for include (master) files and zone files:

> 1. All RRs in the file should have the same class.

So having both NS and MX records in the same include file seems forbidden.

> 2. Exactly one SOA RR should be present at the top of the zone.

Setting the SOA record in an $INCLUDE file appears to be forbidden as well.

> 3. If delegations are present and glue information is required,
>        it should be present.

Apparently [glue records](https://serverfault.com/questions/309622/what-is-a-glue-record) are allowed so `NS` and specific `A` records can be combined in a single include file...

> 4. Information present outside of the authoritative nodes in the
>        zone should be glue information, rather than the result of an
>        origin or similar error.

Comment: Thanks HBruijn for your answer. I understand that i cannot do that.