# Do i have to write NS entries in every zone file using bind9?

Tags: ubuntu, bind

example zone file (domain1.com):

```
@ IN NS dns1.domain.com.
@ IN NS dns2.domain.com.

dns1 IN A **.**.178.93
dns2 IN A **.**.178.93
```

Do i have to declare `IN NS` in every domain zone file using bind9? It is possible to include these entries so i don't need to type it every time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Yes.** [RFC 1033](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1033) states: *"NS records for a domain exist in both the zone that delegates the domain, and in the domain itself"* and therefore `NS` records can not be omitted completely.

Glue records are only needed when the name-servers are within the same zone as the domain. By registering all your domains on the same name-servers you already reduce the effort by half, the zone for `example.org` would then be sufficient with only:

```
@ IN NS ns1.example.com.
@ IN NS ns2.example.com.
```

and doesn't need [glue records](https://serverfault.com/q/309622/37681).

You might even be able use the @INCLUDE option to include the name servers from an second file:

```
@INCLUDE common-zone-data/name-servers.inc ; include common name-servers
```

where name-servers.inc contains the two NS resource records mentioned above.

If all your zones are identical anyway, simply point them to the same zone-file in your named.conf:

```
zone "example.com" {
        type master;
        file "common-zone-data/default.zone";
};
zone "example.org" {
        type master;
        file "common-zone-data/default.zone";
};
```