# DNS resolves self domain

Tags: domain-name-system, bind

I have a couple of domains (`abc.com`, `def.com`, ... , `xyz.com`) and I have a dns server (`ns1.example.com`, `ns2.example.com`). All my domains use `ns1` and `ns2` dot example dot com as their name servers. `example.com` uses Godaddy as its name servers. So far so good. Now I'm thinking whether I can use `example.com` as its own ns servers? Could it cause any problem if I use a dns server to resolve itself? Can there be any chicken-or-egg paradox?

Thanks for pointing me to the glue record, but the answer to glue record still does not make much sense to me.

I found this article about Glue record that seems to make more sense to me: http://www.experts-exchange.com/articles/10297/DNS-Glue-WHAT-and-WHY.html

I recalled that when I started to setup my own dns server. I put in 3 records as Host Names in Godaddy, which is a 3 record map like this:

```
NS1: 12.34.56.78
NS2: 23.45.67.89
NS3: 34.56.78.90
```

Are these records considered glue records?

Comment: Glue Records http://serverfault.com/questions/309622/what-is-a-glue-record

Comment: I don't think the glue record answers this question. So the answer is yes or no?

Comment: Glue records are there to solve the problem you originally imagined.

Comment: So how can I setup glue records for my domain?