# What happens if you have NS domains be resolved by their own NS servers?

Tags: networking, domain-name-system, nameserver, dns-zone

Let me explain.

For example, you have a site, `site.com`, and on the domain provider service, you decide you want to have your own nameservers, and enter the new addresses.

You decide to let these nameservers have domain names, `ns.site.com`.

Now what happens if a client wants to resolve `my.site.com`, as far as i understand it, it (client and/or recursive DNS servers) will ask for authority for the second level domain record of `site.com`, pick the NS name from it, and resolve that to contact it.

Now we have set the nameserver to `ns.site.com`, which lays in it's own domain... wait, that's recursive.

This is exactly what I think could be a problem, how is it solved in the real world? Does/did this ever happen?

Comment: See also: [What is a glue record?](https://serverfault.com/questions/309622/what-is-a-glue-record)

Comment: Well sorry, i did not know that even existed, that's why I'm asking.

Comment: No need to be sorry! :) Without knowing that exact term, it would difficult to search for.

Answer (score 1):

From a [nice post](https://serverfault.com/questions/309622/what-is-a-glue-record) on serverfault

> A glue record is a term for a record that's served by a DNS server
>   that's not authoritative for the zone, to avoid a condition of
>   impossible dependencies for a DNS zone.
>
> Say I own a DNS zone for example.com. I want to have DNS servers
>   that're hosting the authoritative zone for this domain so that I can
>   actually use it - adding records for the root of the domain, www,
>   mail, etc. So, I put the name servers in the registration to delegate
>   to them - those are always names, so we'll put in ns1.example.com and
>   ns2.example.com.
>
> There's the trick. The TLD's servers will delegate to the DNS servers
>   in the whois record - but they're within example.com. They try to find
>   ns1.example.com, ask the .com servers, and get referred back to...
>   ns1.example.com.
>
> What glue records do is to allow the TLD's servers to send extra
>   information in their response to the query for the example.com zone -
>   to send the IP address that's configured for the name servers, too.
>   It's not authoritative, but it's a pointer to the authoritative
>   servers, allowing for the loop to be resolved.