# NS record pointing to subdomain - would this work?

Tags: domain-name-system, subdomain, nameserver, ns-record

I've rented the domain example.com (including *.example.com) at Foobar Domains Inc.. I'd like to have my own nameserver ns1.example.com for example.com and *.example.com.

I can provide an NS record for example.com "ns1.example.com" and an A record for ns1.example.com "192.0.2.1" to ns1.foobardomains.com.

In this situation both ns1.foobardomains.com and ns1.example.com wold provide subdomains of example.com (A/AAAA/MX/...). ns1.foobardomains.com would provide ns1.example.com and ns1.example.com would provide everything else (plus example.com).

But... would this work at all (and why/why not) or would I nuke my own infrastructure? Could there be either a circular dependency tree (ns1.foobardomains.com doesn't feel/seem responsive for *.example.com including ns1.example.com for which only it has the A record due to the NS record) or an "unvisibility" of some subdomains (ns1.foobardomains.com feels/seems responsive for all *.example.com as it has one of them, ns1)?

Answer (score 2):

Actually the NS records for `example.com` are stored in the `.com` zone, so Foobar Domains Inc. will tell the manager of `.com` both the NS record and the A record for `ns1.example.com` (that's called *glue record*).

When someone looks for `www.example.com` he will ask `.com` for an A (or AAAA) record for `www.example.com` but the server (being non recursive) will just answer "I only know that the NS server for example.com is `ns1.example.com` and the A record for that name is `x.x.x.x`".

If someone looks for the A record `ns1.example.com` then the `.com` server will answer immediately since it has the glue record saved.

Comment: So nameservers always tell everything they know despite NS records? Nice.

Comment: Yes, you can learn more about **glue records** in this [canonical question](https://serverfault.com/questions/309622/what-is-a-glue-record)