# Why does DNS return an FQDN with glue record instead of IP

Tags: domain-name-system, hostname

When I send out a DNS request for `my.example.net`, my DNS recursive server goes to the DNS root zone (or gets some cached value instead). That nameserver says "go look at the `.net` nameservers", and those in turn say "look at the `example.net` nameservers" and those in turn say "`my.example.net` is at `xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx`".

Wikipedia says that "Name servers in delegations are identified by name, rather than by IP address," and the necessity of [glue records](https://serverfault.com/questions/309622/what-is-a-glue-record) supports this.

Question 1:

I don't understand how the DNS root zone telling me to go to `a.gtld-servers.net` (or whatever the .net nameserver is) to resolve `my.example.net` can help, since the `.net` nameservers have `.net` in them and I don't have an IP address. Is it just a glue record at the TLD level?

Question 2:

If glue records are such a required part of DNS, why do delegations happen by hostname instead of IP address?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. People who run recursive resolvers (e.g. Google with 8.8.8.8, or your ISP) need to have IP address of at least one root server provided - usually via hints file. Root server's IPs are [documented by IANA](https://www.iana.org/domains/root/servers) and rarely change.
2. Makes it easier for non-root DNS servers to change IP, or to have multiple, or to give different IP to different regions / etc.

Comment: In regards to 1, I understand the DNS root zone IP must be required. I don't understand how that root nameserver saying "go look at the `.net` nameservers at nameserver.net" does so without a circular dependency. Do all TLDs have glue records in the DNS root zone?

Comment: @jeremysprofile ah, sorry - I misunderstood your question. Interesting point, it appears yes - glue records will be needed. Run `dig +trace +additional test.net. SO` - it appears there's quite a lot of information passed via additional section.

Answer (score 1):

All recursive nameserver software are shipped with the list of current root nameservers and their IP addresses.

This gives a basis as this can change but slowly.

Upon start, the server will connect any of the above IP address to retrieve, through a `. NS` DNS query the current list of root nameservers, and then update its internal list and use that for all further needs. This process is called "priming".

If you want details, this is all explained in [RFC 8109 "Initializing a DNS Resolver with Priming Queries"](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc8109)

As for your question on glues, remember that glues are a specific edge case. If you have domain `adomain.example` using `ns1.anotherdomain.test` then there are no glue records anywhere. See the definition of "glue records" in this new document on DNS terminology: https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7719#section-6 :

> Glue records:  "[Resource records] which are not part of the
> authoritative data [of the zone], and are address resource records
> for the [name servers in subzones].  These RRs are only necessary
> if the name server's name is 'below' the cut, and are only used as
> part of a referral response."  Without glue "we could be faced
> with the situation where the NS RRs tell us that in order to learn
> a name server's address, we should contact the server using the
> address we wish to learn."  (Definition from [RFC1034],
> Section 4.2.1)

As for "When I send out a DNS request for my.example.net, it goes to the DNS root zone" no, this is not true. Your system uses one (or multiple) recursive DNS servers, either locally or public. You send all your DNS queries to them. They are in charge, like their name imply, to do iterative queries to multiple nameservers, in a recursive fashion, starting from the root, if their current cache has no data to reply to your query.

So let us describe with an example, using a real name, like `www.stackexchange.com`.

You can do `dig +trace www.stackexchange.com A` to see exactly what happens, the `+trace` triggers full recursive mode and shows what any recursive nameserver does when its cache is empty.

But we can redo it manually.
And if you want the specific algorithm to follow, have a read at "4.3.2. Algorithm" in [RFC 1034 DOMAIN NAMES - CONCEPTS AND FACILITIES](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1034) (but note that there are later additions, specially for DNSSEC and other records like DNAME)

For example see https://gitlab.isc.org/isc-projects/bind9/blob/master/lib/dns/rootns.c
This is part of BIND source code. But it is basically the content of a reply for `. NS` with IP addresses, that is current list of root nameservers and their IPv4 and IPv6 addresses.

We ignore the DNS priming step here (updating the above list)

## Step 1

Pick one of the above IP addresses and do your query:

```
$ dig @192.112.36.4 www.stackexchange.com A +nodnssec

; <<>> DiG 9.12.0 <<>> @192.112.36.4 www.stackexchange.com A +nodnssec
; (1 server found)
;; global options: +cmd
;; Sending:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 59725
;; flags: rd ad; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 0, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 1

;; QUESTION SECTION:
;www.stackexchange.com. IN A

;; QUERY SIZE: 62

;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 59725
;; flags: qr rd; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 0, AUTHORITY: 13, ADDITIONAL: 27
;; WARNING: recursion requested but not available

;; QUESTION SECTION:
;www.stackexchange.com. IN A

;; AUTHORITY SECTION:
com.            2d IN NS k.gtld-servers.net.
com.            2d IN NS e.gtld-servers.net.
com.            2d IN NS g.gtld-servers.net.
com.            2d IN NS c.gtld-servers.net.
com.            2d IN NS l.gtld-servers.net.
com.            2d IN NS j.gtld-servers.net.
com.            2d IN NS h.gtld-servers.net.
com.            2d IN NS a.gtld-servers.net.
com.            2d IN NS b.gtld-servers.net.
com.            2d IN NS m.gtld-servers.net.
com.            2d IN NS d.gtld-servers.net.
com.            2d IN NS f.gtld-servers.net.
com.            2d IN NS i.gtld-servers.net.

;; ADDITIONAL SECTION:
a.gtld-servers.net. 2d IN A 192.5.6.30
b.gtld-servers.net. 2d IN A 192.33.14.30
c.gtld-servers.net. 2d IN A 192.26.92.30
d.gtld-servers.net. 2d IN A 192.31.80.30
e.gtld-servers.net. 2d IN A 192.12.94.30
f.gtld-servers.net. 2d IN A 192.35.51.30
g.gtld-servers.net. 2d IN A 192.42.93.30
h.gtld-servers.net. 2d IN A 192.54.112.30
i.gtld-servers.net. 2d IN A 192.43.172.30
j.gtld-servers.net. 2d IN A 192.48.79.30
k.gtld-servers.net. 2d IN A 192.52.178.30
l.gtld-servers.net. 2d IN A 192.41.162.30
m.gtld-servers.net. 2d IN A 192.55.83.30
a.gtld-servers.net. 2d IN AAAA 2001:503:a83e::2:30
b.gtld-servers.net. 2d IN AAAA 2001:503:231d::2:30
c.gtld-servers.net. 2d IN AAAA 2001:503:83eb::30
d.gtld-servers.net. 2d IN AAAA 2001:500:856e::30
e.gtld-servers.net. 2d IN AAAA 2001:502:1ca1::30
f.gtld-servers.net. 2d IN AAAA 2001:503:d414::30
g.gtld-servers.net. 2d IN AAAA 2001:503:eea3::30
h.gtld-servers.net. 2d IN AAAA 2001:502:8cc::30
i.gtld-servers.net. 2d IN AAAA 2001:503:39c1::30
j.gtld-servers.net. 2d IN AAAA 2001:502:7094::30
k.gtld-servers.net. 2d IN AAAA 2001:503:d2d::30
l.gtld-servers.net. 2d IN AAAA 2001:500:d937::30
m.gtld-servers.net. 2d IN AAAA 2001:501:b1f9::30

;; Query time: 121 msec
;; SERVER: 192.112.36.4#53(192.112.36.4)
;; WHEN: Tue Mar 26 12:22:23 EST 2019
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 874
```

So the server at `192.112.36.4` is replying to us:

- `NOERROR`: our request was valid
- no `aa` entry in the flags, we did not get an authoritative reply to our answer, just pointers on where to go next
- "WARNING: recursion requested but not available": as expected the authoritative nameserver on `.` we query does no do recursion for us
- so this server knows, to help our request, only authoritative nameservers on `.COM`; it provides their names and IP addresses.

Now, the recursive nameserver is not mandated to trust the content of the "ADDITIONAL SECTION". It could go again with `m.gtld-servers.net.` for example and ask the same authoritative nameserver about it. In the same way it will give back data that it is not authoritative on this name but knows nameservers of `.NET` and giving back their name and IP addresses. Here, since their names are all again in `.NET`, they are in-bailiwick, and the server has to trust the IP addresses provided.

## Step 2

Picking up any of the above IP addresses, we do our query again:

$ dig @192.26.92.30 [www.stackexchange.com](http://www.stackexchange.com) A +nodnssec

```
; <<>> DiG 9.12.0 <<>> @192.26.92.30 www.stackexchange.com A +nodnssec
; (1 server found)
;; global options: +cmd
;; Sending:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 45273
;; flags: rd ad; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 0, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 1

;; QUESTION SECTION:
;www.stackexchange.com. IN A

;; QUERY SIZE: 62

;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 45273
;; flags: qr rd; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 0, AUTHORITY: 4, ADDITIONAL: 5
;; WARNING: recursion requested but not available

;; QUESTION SECTION:
;www.stackexchange.com. IN A

;; AUTHORITY SECTION:
stackexchange.com.  2d IN NS ns-925.awsdns-51.net.
stackexchange.com.  2d IN NS ns-1029.awsdns-00.org.
stackexchange.com.  2d IN NS ns-cloud-d1.googledomains.com.
stackexchange.com.  2d IN NS ns-cloud-d2.googledomains.com.

;; ADDITIONAL SECTION:
ns-cloud-d1.googledomains.com. 2d IN AAAA 2001:4860:4802:32::6d
ns-cloud-d1.googledomains.com. 2d IN A 216.239.32.109
ns-cloud-d2.googledomains.com. 2d IN AAAA 2001:4860:4802:34::6d
ns-cloud-d2.googledomains.com. 2d IN A 216.239.34.109

;; Query time: 108 msec
;; SERVER: 192.26.92.30#53(192.26.92.30)
;; WHEN: Tue Mar 26 12:35:56 EST 2019
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 273
```

Here the server at `192.26.92.30` provides us with roughly the same kind of answer previously: it is not authoritative for the name we seek about, but provides back its nameserver and IP addresses.

Again, the namserver could not go ask for the name `ns-cloud-d1.googledomains.com.` but it will obviously come from the same namserver, as same TLD, so it can use above IP addresses. Or it can do the resolution from scratch again for names `ns-925.awsdns-51.net.` or `ns-1029.awsdns-00.org.` which are external to the `.COM` zone, hence no IP addresses provided.

## Step 3

So to simplify using one of the above IP addresses and redoing the query:

```
$ dig @216.239.34.109 www.stackexchange.com A +nodnssec

; <<>> DiG 9.12.0 <<>> @216.239.34.109 www.stackexchange.com A +nodnssec
; (1 server found)
;; global options: +cmd
;; Sending:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 16720
;; flags: rd ad; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 0, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 1

;; QUESTION SECTION:
;www.stackexchange.com. IN A

;; QUERY SIZE: 62

;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 16720
;; flags: qr aa rd; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 5, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 1
;; WARNING: recursion requested but not available

;; QUESTION SECTION:
;www.stackexchange.com. IN A

;; ANSWER SECTION:
www.stackexchange.com.  5m IN CNAME stackexchange.com.
stackexchange.com.  5m IN A 151.101.1.69
stackexchange.com.  5m IN A 151.101.65.69
stackexchange.com.  5m IN A 151.101.129.69
stackexchange.com.  5m IN A 151.101.193.69

;; Query time: 149 msec
;; SERVER: 216.239.34.109#53(216.239.34.109)
;; WHEN: Tue Mar 26 12:38:34 EST 2019
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 128
```

Note an important difference: the AA flag, meaning that the nameserver we just queried is indeed authoritative on the name we were querying so its results are "final".
In fact it shows that our name is a `CNAME` record type, but it does provide the IP addresses of the target, so our query is finished, we were able to resolve that `www.stackexchange.com` right now and from where this was done, is IP addresses `151.101.1.69` and `151.101.65.69` and `151.101.129.69` and `151.101.193.69`.

Comment: so my recursive nameserver starts trying to resolve "my.example.net" at the root nameserver. The root nameserver gives it a hostname for where to find the .net TLD nameservers. How does my recursive nameserver resolve the hostname it receives? That hostname has to be in some sort of domain, and we don't currently have an IP for any TLD nameserver.

Comment: @jeremysprofile see updated reply with full example

Comment: I have a circular dependency every time I try to resolve a TLD, which is why we have to use the additional section even though it's not authoritative. So the answer to question 1 is "yes, every cacheless DNS request must use a glue record"?

Comment: No.  `dig ORG. NS` gives you 6 nameservers, three of which in `.INFO`. No circular dependency. `dig MUSEUM. NS` gives you 3 nameservers, all in `.FR`. And many other examples.

Comment: For `ORG.`, you'll have to resolve `.INFO`. For `MUSEUM.` you'll have to resolve `.FR`. Whichever TLD you end up resolving (through whatever chain of TLDs) will have to be accomplished by the IPs in the `ADDITIONAL` section from the root zone. I was (maybe mistakenly) calling this a glue record. Is there a word for when you are not necessarily in-bailiwick but still require the `ADDITIONAL` section to proceed?

Comment: Maybe this sentence from RFC 1035 helps: "NS records cause both the usual additional section processing to locate
a type A record, and, when used in a referral, a special search of the
zone in which they reside for glue information." and the associated definition of DNS packet format: "The answer section contains RRs that answer the
question; the authority section contains RRs that point toward an
authoritative name server; the additional records section contains RRs
which relate to the query, but are not strictly answers for the
question."

Comment: Let me try a rephrase. "Every cacheless DNS request requires information from `ADDITIONAL`, and sometimes this information is called a `glue record` when the nameserver is in-bailiwick"?

Comment: "Every cacheless DNS request requires information from ADDITIONAL" No, not in general. ADDITIONAL helps in delegations but is not authoritative. Results are normally in the ANSWER section.

Comment: Sorry, I phrased that poorly. I meant "every cacheless DNS FQDN request at one point requires information from ADDITIONAL", because at some point the root DNS server must provide non-authoritative information about where the TLD nameservers are. There are multiple requests in the chain as the recursive system tries to figure out the end IP address, but at least one of those requests at some point must use information from ADDITIONAL to get to a TLD.