# freeipa on subdomain - can't resolve A records

Tags: domain-name-system, freeipa

I just installed an freeipa server (with an master replica) for our infrastructure. For the freeipa domain I used an subdomain (of our real domain) e.g. "internal.foobar.com", and made two A records for the nameservers ns1.internal.foobar.com,ns2.internal.foobar.com for my subdomain, and those nameservers are my freeipa servers.

But the problem is that those A records (for the nameservers) don't resolve to an IP adress, when I try host ns1.internal.foobar.com I get "Host ns1.internal.foobar.com not found: 3(NXDOMAIN)". But if I try to resolve a specific client on my freeipa domain, like test.internal.foobar.com it resolves it fine (most of the time - sometimes it timesout). I was just wondering, is this problem something that I configured badly or is it something on the dns register side?

Tnx,
Tom

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the description, it looks like you are missing glue records in foobar.com for NS servers for internal.foobar.com. See [What is a glue record?](https://serverfault.com/questions/309622/what-is-a-glue-record) for details.

Comment: I've got the two A records for my nameservers, and those are the glue records...

Comment: Your glue records need to be located in foobar.com, not in internal.foobar.com. You can add ns1-internal.foobar.com pointing to IP address of ns1.internal.foobar.com and then mark ns1-internal.foobar.com as your NS record for internal.foobar.com.

Comment: that's exactly what I did, the two domains aren't separated I left it all in the foobar.com domain...the internal.foobar.com is just an ns record for the nameservers...

Comment: I was an idiot and read you answer wrongly, it worked with the A record of  ns1-internal.foobar.com instead of ns1.internal.foobar.com....tnx